# Counting Number of words and Characters in a Sentence using C

Tags: c

I tried the below program .

INPUT-: i want help 
Desired OUTPUT-:Words=3 Characters=9

But the actual output deviates from the desired.
Can someone tell what is my mistake .

## include

```
void main()
{
  int countch=0;
  int countwd=1;

  printf("Enter your sentence in lowercase: ");
  char ch='a';
  while(ch!='\r')
  {
    ch=getche();
    if(ch==' ')
      countwd++;
    else
      countch++;
  }

  printf("\n Words = ",countwd);

  printf("Characters = ",countch-1);

  getch();

}
```

Comment: @JAM please once show me coding conventions  of formatting a program i will follow from now Thanks

Comment: Are you running on Linux/unix/mac or on Windows?

Comment: what if there is no \r ? Also, what about double-spaces?

Comment: @VijayKumar Not everyone can format someone else's code. All you need to do to format your code is to insert four spaces in front of your statement on each line.

Comment: i am running on windows in the website http://codepad.org/

Comment: @dasblinkenlight thank you i will do it

Comment: What output do you have ? I count 3 words and 9 characters in "i want help".

Comment: I doubt codepad is running on windows *grin* http://codepad.org/ZztFiQLU

Comment: but the output is error
In function `main':
undefined reference to `getche'
undefined reference to `getch'

Comment: @KarolyHorvath do you mean my program will work fine on turbo c?

Comment: `getch` & `getche` are non standard functions. You are probably better off using [`getchar`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/getchar.html).

Comment: @VijayKumar if you think that `main: undefined reference to getche' undefined reference to 'getch'` is the output of your program, I guess that you need first to read a good book about C programming.

Comment: Also please use `int` as the return type for `main` instead of `void`

Comment: @another.anon.coward but when i changed getch & getche to getchar i am getting error TIMEOUT

Comment: download gcc (or any other C compiler) and do not use online compiler websites, if you do not have much experience with C. It is much easier and complies better to C books. In your case: I suppose codepad cannot read chars from the keyboard (as your keyboard in not connected to the server...)

Comment: @Veger,@Coren,@Karoly Horvath i tried by using \n in place of \r but it is not working can u plz help me to understand 
char ch='a';
  while(ch!='\r')
the function of these two lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few observations which you might find of some use:
1. You are using `getch` & `getche` which are both non-standard functions. Make use of [`getchar`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/getchar.html) instead. In this case as already pointed in [unwind's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9567598/925381) you need to use `int` for the return type.
2. Please change the return type of `main` from `void` to `int`.
3. You are not specifying the formats in `printf`. Please add `%d` specifier to print integers.
I have not used codepad but ideone allows you to add inputs to your programs. [Here](http://ideone.com/Uadte) is a reference based on your sample on ideone.
Hope this helps!

Comment: @VijayKumar: Basically, you keep reading characters from input till you encounter `'\n'` using `getchar()`. You increment the word counter when you encounter a <Space> character that means space is the word separator i.e. words are separated by <Space> else if it is not a <Space> character the chracter read is treated as a valid character and you increment your character counter. Finally, when you encounter `'\n'` you break out of the loop wherein you are reading characters & display the counts

Comment: char ch='a';
  while(ch!='\r')
can you explain these two lines

Comment: @karthikgorijavolu: `char ch='a';` initializes `ch` to `a` & the `while` is to run the loop till `\n` is encountered

Comment: @karthik gorijavolu: `\r` is carriage return, `\n` is line feed. You can look it up to find out what is what. [These](http://www.cre8asiteforums.com/forums/index.php?showtopic=43934) [link](http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/5A5A050A3019A573862575F30061D49B) provide some pointers for starters

Comment: i have checked that link but did not got the explanation of these two lines
char ch='a'; while(ch!='\r')
why we have to initialize with 'a' and why we have to run the loop till \r?

Comment: @karthikgorijavolu: You can initialize `ch` to anything but `\r` otherwise the `while` loop will not be entered, so it is being initialized to `'a'`. The `while` loop is to read inputs till a return carriage `\r` is entered which indicates according to the program logic that user is done entering & the program can shows the words & characters

Answer (score 3):

Be advised: `getchar()` returns `int`, not `char`. This is one of the most common pitfalls for beginning C programmers, it seems.

Also, you should check for the special value `EOF` and stop the program if it occurs; this is the typical and "clean" way of doing programs that read input and will make the program automatically handle both interactive input (from a terminal) and input from a file.

Comment: so what are the modifications i need to do in my program

Comment: Modify `ch` to the `int` type and replace `getche` with `getchar`

Comment: Curious, why worry about getchar() returning int? if you have variable ch as char then ch=getchar() would coerce getchar to char, would it not? No need to explicitly cast or anything. That is where is the pitfall?

Comment: `getchar` returns an `int`, when you store it in a `char` you (might) lose data!

Comment: @Sint yea can you explain this line while(ch!='\r')

Comment: @Sint The problem is with EOF; it's not a character, so it needs to have a representation that is larger than a character in order to fit. Otherwise you would clobber a valid character with the EOF value, which would not be very nice.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdbool.h>

int main(void)
{
char c = '\0';
int nw = 0,nc = 0,nl = 0;

bool flag = true;
bool last = false,cur = false;

while(flag && (c = getchar())) {

    if(c != EOF)
        ++nc;
    else
        flag = false;

    if(c == '\n') nl++;

    cur = (c == EOF || c == ' ' || c == '\t' || c == '\n')?false:true;

     if(last  && !cur )
        ++nw;

    last = cur;
}


printf("\nNo of chars : %d",nc);
printf("\nNo of lines : %d",nl);
printf("\nNo of words : %d",nw);

return 0;
}
```